# Duda en estructura de base de datos

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, lista

Estoy haciendo un proyecto web sobre peliculas, donde hay comentarios, listas de peliculas y más... Soy un poco novato y tengo bastantes dudas de como desarrollar la base de datos y quería sabe si me podriais echar una mano, por que hay cosas que no tengo muy claro, o que pienso que podria optimizarse.
[image: Base de datos]

Tengo dudas sobre todo con la parte de directores y actores (Arriba)
y con la parte de enlaces guion y genero.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Lamentablemente tu pregunta es basada en opiniones, motivo por el cual terminará cerrada. En [es.so] resolvemos dudas puntuales y específicas. Cuando tengas una duda específica sobre alguna implementación, error o comportamiento inesperado, con gusto te podremos ayudar. Si tu pregunta es para pedir opiniones sobre un tema específico de diseño, este no es el sitio para hacerlo. Saludos

Comment: Tu pregunta, me parece, trata sobre la forma de establecer las relaciones entre las tablas. Creo que la pregunta indicada más arriba puede ayudarte en la situación actual. Si aún quedan dudas debes plantearlas de forma concreta, indicando qué problema concreto tienes, mostrando el diseño de las tablas, un Ejemplo Mínimo y Verificable, el resultado de las pruebas, etc. Será todo eso lo que hará que preguntas de este tipo no sean consideradas como basadas en opiniones.